# Adding to or subtracting from a distressed mask/overlay mask using 100% opacity pixels in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask

I have a texture that I'm using as a layer mask to create a distressed "grunge" effect for a DTG T-Shirt design. Because its not being printed on high quality DTG, the mask can only consist of 100% black and 0% opacity pixels (no grey or semi-transparent). This is what part of it looks like this when zoomed WAY in:
[image]. It works well for the most part, but there are areas where I want/need to go in manually and paint onto the mask using black or white to fine tune things a bit. To do so, I'm using a brush that looks like this:
[image]

I have flow and opacity and hardness set to 100% and nothing checked for Brush Tip Shape, but it still antialiases the individual particles within when I just click once in place (without moving the mouse while clicking). From what I've read there is no way to turn anti-aliasing off for a brush. Is this accurate?

I also tried recreating a similar set of particles with the pencil tool and defining a pattern with it in the hopes of using the stamp pattern tool. This came closer to working but depending on the brush chosen, it turned some of the pixels around the edges grey.

Is there any way to be able to stamp this pattern of particles with different sized brushes (that is 100% necessary for the fine-tuning I'm doing) and have it only produce 100% opacity pixels of #ffffff or #000000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than the Brush Tool, choose the Pencil Tool for solid pixels, set to 1px.  Add Scattering and jitter in the Brush Settings

An example [image]

Answer (score 4):

Work your image in Bitmap color mode. It cannot have any intermediate shades. You can turn it later to grayscale or even RGB. No antialiasing blur creeps in as long as you do not insert nor edit anything after converting the color mode from bitmap to something else.

Comment: In Photoshop "bitmap color mode" is 1-bit color mode in other applications.